# Android - How to bring to front a webview

Tags: android, layout, view, webview

I have two `Webviews` but at certain point i would like to bring the one on the back to front. I want both visible.

Is it possible to change the layout order?

Comment: When you say you want both visible... do you mean at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

There is no concept of Z-axis position in Android view stack so you can't bring views to front or send to back.  You need to set the view's visibility flag to hide, visible or invisible (.setVisibility(GONE , VISIBLE, or INVISIBLE) respectively).  If you want them both visible at times then you need to have at least the top view (the one added to the parent view last) be with transparent background so that if their Visibilities are set to VISIBLE then the behind view will show through the top view.

Kevin